# node.js get after post

Tags: node.js, concurrency

I had a scenario for node.js where I don't know what will happen. Assume someone issues a post request that is followed by another get request for the same resource. The post request inserts into a db, takes some time, during which node serves the get request. Since the resource hasn't been added to DB yet, node responds to the get request with an error.

My questions:

a)Is this scenario possible?

b)If so, ideally shouldn't it return the resource? How should I avoid such concurrency issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about it. If you are properly implementing a url based service then, the process should be as follows:

1. client POST a new data item. Using url to data collection.
2. data posted, response has unique url to access newly inserted data item.
3. now client GET data item from this url.

Client **should not assume or guess the future url of newly inserted item, without being confirmed by server**. Client can obtain data item's url:

1. By doing a GET for data collection, and picking up a url to one of the data items.
2. By doing a POST with new data, and response of that successful post returns url of new data item.

Comment: what if my resource is an entire table ie get on entire table but post only a row(I know I said same resource, but just curious)? Shouldn't I assume the client to know the GET url because it's always the same ?

Comment: @user2103008 Client may know the GET url of the table, and actually get the table, no problem. But client must not expect it to contain updated data, until confirmation response of POST is received.

Comment: @user2103008 I've updated answer to show difference between `data collection` and `data item`.